# Digestibility of cocoa/cacao butter in white chocolate

Tags: chocolate, sugar

I know that if I were to eat a chunk of cocoa/cacao butter on its own, my body wouldn't really digest it well. Typically, for large amounts of fat, they need to be emulsified to be digested. However, if one just adds some sugar, the cocoa/cacao butter becomes digestible white chocolate. Since sugar is only polar, I don't think it should be able to emulsify cocoa/cacao butter. Is my understanding of all this horribly wrong? How much sugar needs to be added to cocoa/cacao butter to make it digestible? Are there other ways to make cocoa/cacao butter more digestible?